# How to get an page instance from a block instance on a admin edit page?

Tags: wagtail

I have a custom wagtail PageChooserBlock.

```
class SelectThroughBlock(wblocks.PageChooserBlock):
    @cached_property
    def field(self):
        from django import forms
        return forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=self.target_model.objects.all(), widget=self.widget, required=self.required,
            help_text=self.help_text)

    @cached_property
    def widget(self):
        from django.forms.widgets import Select
        return Select()
```

How can I get an instance of edit page in wagtail admin?

Answer (score 0):

The admin edit url for a `Page` can be accessed via the id of an instance.

```
my_page = Page.objects.get(pk=2)
reverse("wagtailadmin_pages:edit",args=(my_page.pk,))
```

Or in a template:

```
{% url 'wagtailadmin_pages:edit' page.id %}
```

As such, you can call the reverse url for the edit page anywhere you have access to the Page instance.